# (Android) Check a value at IntentExtra made by Hashmap

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to adjust "if" base on value from another activity through IntentExtra made by Hashmap. The situation;

---

A Java Class

Hashmap

Insert a value at String

Put a value at Intent Extra

Sent Intent

---

B java class

get Intent Extra

put Extra at String

Check using "if" to know which value handedover.

---

The problem is last one.

Code on B activity is like this.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mapKey;
    mapKey = intent.getStringExtra(MAPMARKER);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mapKey,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(mapKey == "Donhawmun") {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
        readingpart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readingPart);
        DonImageClass adapter = new DonImageClass(getLayoutInflater());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        readingpart.setText(R.string.Don);
    }else if(mapKey == "Geumcheongyo"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
        readingpart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readingPart);
        GeumImageClass adapter = new GeumImageClass(getLayoutInflater());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        readingpart.setText(R.string.Geum);
    }
```

By first "Toast" is good, so it toast a messege "Donhawmun".

But it doesn't match with a text "Donhawmun".

I wonder if it has a problem match with a text directly, I made another String "Donhawmun" and put it in "if" sentence to compare it. But it didn't works. I'm not sure that it already show mapKey value as "Donhawmun", but why it didn't match with "Donhawmun" in if sentence. Please help me anybody who has an idea. Thank you inadvance.

Comment: Don't use (==) operator for comparing two strings. It is done by equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() method. Your code will look like if(mapKey.equals("Donhawmun"))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use equal method to compare strings. So use following code.

```
if(mapKey.equals("Donhawmun")) {
  ...
}else if(mapKey.equals("Geumcheongyo")){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't match with a text "Donhawmun".

You should consider using `equals()` instead of `==`

Here is why!

`==`        is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location.
`.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
if(mapKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Donhawmun")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
    readingpart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readingPart);
    DonImageClass adapter = new DonImageClass(getLayoutInflater());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    readingpart.setText(R.string.Don);
}else if(mapKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Geumcheongyo")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
    readingpart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readingPart);
    GeumImageClass adapter = new GeumImageClass(getLayoutInflater());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    readingpart.setText(R.string.Geum);
}
```

You cannot compare string using "==".

Answer (score 0):

use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() method

```
if(mapkey.equalsIgnorCase("Donhawmun"))
{
......
}
else if(mapkey.equalsIgnorCase("Geumcheongyo"))
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your B class try this

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mapKey = intent.getStringExtra(MAPMARKER);

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && mapKey.equals("Donhawmun")) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
            readingpart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readingPart);
            DonImageClass adapter = new DonImageClass(getLayoutInflater());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            readingpart.setText(R.string.Don);
        }else if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && mapKey.equals("Geumcheongyo")){ 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
            readingpart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readingPart);
            GeumImageClass adapter = new GeumImageClass(getLayoutInflater());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            readingpart.setText(R.string.Geum);
        }
```